# Toolbar trouble while implementing Material Design

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-toolbar

UPDATE: I tried setting the themes as Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar. I get this:

```
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667): Process: com.example.app, PID: 10667
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$2
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:304)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at com.teamidentiti.aoesoundboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-19 21:36:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I've referred to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) guide. I have imported appcompat_v7 in Eclipse and referenced it as a library in my app.

I have only one styles.xml file in values folder with the applied theme's parent as - Theme.AppCompat.Light

This is the main activity's XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red500" />

    <com.example.app.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:background="@drawable/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:onClick="showFavs" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snackbar"
        android:textSize="@dimen/snackbar_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/snackbar_side_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/snackbar_side_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/snackbar_top_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/snackbar_bottom_padding"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#323232" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my code, I get the following errors:

```
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): Process: com.example.app, PID: 9124
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:273)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     ... 10 more
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     ... 21 more
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$1
11-19 21:09:51.157: E/AndroidRuntime(9124):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:91)
```

I just don't get what's happening with the ActionBarOverlayLayout... Help appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: are you setting the Toolbar as you actionbar?

Comment: @MREngineer13 Yes I am!

Comment: Ok try changing your theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. And could you post the Toolbar relevant code from your activity

Comment: @MrEngineer13 I'm doing nothing much except -

`Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` sounds like you didn't set up the support library correctly. Did you follow these instructions? https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: @MrEngineer13 I just went through it again, I've done everything. Still the same updated error log!

Comment: @sravan953 did you got anything?? m facing same